# How to use Python 3.x with Python(x,y)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pythonxy

I've installed Python(x,y), and it's using Python 2.7.9.

I saw the post [Python 3.x on python(x,y)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053262/python-3-x-on-pythonx-y), but I did not see the answer to my questions.

1) Currently Python(x,y) Version 2.7.9.0 comes with Python 2.7.9.  Can I use Python 3.x with Python(x,y)?

2) If yes to 1), then how do I install Python 3.x to be used with Python(x,y)?

Comment: Python(x,y) is not currently available for Python 3.x

Comment: @Matt I know I can't download a version of Python(x,y) that comes with Python 3.x, but are you sure there is not a way to point Python(x,y) to a Python 3.x?

Comment: No, it is only compatible with python 2.x. Do you need to use Python 3.x for any reason?

Comment: @Matt I have a package I'm trying to install, and I was told it needs Python 3.4.

Comment: what is name of the package?

Comment: @Matt It's a private package for work.  I'll have to double check that it really needs Python 3.4, and if so, then use something other than Python(x,y).

Comment: ok, @theblackcat suggested some alternatives below

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot use Python 3.x with Python(x,y) at the present time.  Support is planned, but last I heard it will come after 64bit support, which isn't available yet either.  If you need Python 3.x, use Winpython, Anaconda, or Enthought Canopy.